# How to swipe and delete element?

Tags: android

I have tested multiple libraries swipegestures or using itemtouchhelper I also tried use SwipeReavealLayoutl...

If I implement it like in every guide I have got wrong adapter position and it is not deleted.

My implementation, viewmodel:

```
    fun onItemSwiped(id: Int) {
            ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                override fun onMove(
                    v: RecyclerView,
                    h: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                    t: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                ) = false

                override fun onSwiped(h: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dir: Int) {
                    deleteItem(id)
                    ItemTouchHelper.ViewDropHandler { view, target, x, y -> }
                }
            })

    }
```

adapter

```
   inner class NotificationItemViewHolder(
        private val layout: LayoutListItemNotificationBinding,
    ) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(layout.root) {
        fun bind(item: NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData) = with(layout.vContent) {

// these two works
            btnClose.setOnClickListener { onItemDeleteClicked(item.id) }
            root.setOnClickListener {
                onItemRootClicked(item.leadId)
            }

// doesnt work
            onItemSwiped(item.id)
```

fragment

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        notificationAdapter = NotificationAdapter(vm::deleteItem, vm::onItemClicked, vm::onItemSwiped)
```

If I try to manage id from fragment like:

```
        var pos = viewHolder.absoluteAdapterPosition
```

I get weird position -1 or 2131296679

i.e my previous implementation from fragment when I could swipe but it wasn't deleted and swiped element came back to previous position.

```
    private fun onSwipeDelete() =
        ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            override fun onMove(v: RecyclerView, h: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, t: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) = false
            override fun onSwiped(h: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dir: Int) {

                vm.onItemSwiped(h.absoluteAdapterPosition)
                notificationAdapter.deleteItem(h.absoluteAdapterPosition)

                ItemTouchHelper.ViewDropHandler { view, target, x, y ->  }
            notificationAdapter.notifyItemChanged(h.absoluteAdapterPosition)}
        }).attachToRecyclerView(layout.rvNotificationItems)
```

How should I handle this in that case?
When I have direct element I can use in adapter I can easily handle it.. How to react for swiping in adapter?
Now it doesn't even swipe..

greetings

EDIT1:

```
class NotificationAdapter(
    private val onItemDeleteClicked: (Int) -> Unit,
    private val onItemRootClicked: (Int) -> Unit,
    private val onItemSwiped: (Int) -> Unit
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationItemViewHolder>() {
    var items = emptyList<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>()
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotificationItemViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return LayoutListItemNotificationBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
            .let(::NotificationItemViewHolder)
        setListData(items)

        val mIth = ItemTouchHelper(
            object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
                0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
            ) {
                override fun onMove(
                    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                    viewHolder: ViewHolder, target: ViewHolder
                ): Boolean {
                   return false // true if moved, false otherwise
                }

                override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                    deleteItem(viewHolder.absoluteAdapterPosition)
                }
            })
    }

   inner class NotificationItemViewHolder(
        private val layout: LayoutListItemNotificationBinding,
    ) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(layout.root) {
        fun bind(item: NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData) = with(layout.vContent) {
           btnClose.setOnClickListener { onItemDeleteClicked(item.id) }
            root.setOnClickListener {
               onItemRootClicked(item.leadId)
            }

            ItemTouchHelper(
                object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
                    0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
                ) {
                    override fun onMove(
                        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                        viewHolder: ViewHolder, target: ViewHolder
                    ): Boolean {

                       return false // true if moved, false otherwise
                    }

                    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                        deleteItem(item.id)
                    }
                })

   override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    fun setListData(list: List<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>) {
        this.items = list

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    // nie uzywane
    fun deleteItem(id: Int) {
        onItemDeleteClicked(id)
        notifyItemRemoved(id)
        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    fun onSwipe(id: Int) =
        ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            override fun onMove(
                v: RecyclerView,
                h: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                t: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ) = false

            override fun onSwiped(h: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dir: Int) {
                deleteItem(id)
                ItemTouchHelper.ViewDropHandler { view, target, x, y -> }
            }
        })
}}
```

EDIT2:
OK from my understanding:
I use anonymous function in adapter:

```
private val onItemDeleteClicked: (Int) -> Unit,
```

then I can call it from viewmodel:

```
fun getActualState() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getNotificationListItemDetailsUseCase.build(Unit).collect {
                notificationData.value = it
                Log.d("test2", "${notificationData.value}")

            }
        }
    }

    fun deleteItem(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            deleteNotificationListItemDetailsUseCase.build(id)
            getActualState()
        }
```

then in fragment I init my adapter

```
   private lateinit var notificationAdapter: NotificationAdapter

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        notificationAdapter = NotificationAdapter(vm::deleteItem, vm::onItemClicked, vm::onItemSwiped)
```

Comment: on swipe delete items from the adapter as well and notify the adapter

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the following to delete item from the adapter

`notificationAdapter.deleteItem(h.absoluteAdapterPosition)`

and the following to notify the adapter :

`notificationAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0)`

instead you should notify the removal of item

`notificationAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(h.absoluteAdapterPosition)`

[EDIT 01] : pseudo approach to remove item from the adapter [java]

```
...
private List<Object> data = new ArrayList()


public void removeItem(int index){
    data.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
}
...
```

you should do something like above

[EDIT 02] : possible bugs in your code

look at this snippet from your code

```
fun deleteItem(id: Int) {
    onItemDeleteClicked(id)
    notifyItemRemoved(id)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

if you have called `notifyItemRemoved` then there is no need to call `notifyDataSetChanged`

moreover there is no line in whole code which actually removes the item from the `items` object.

modify your code to the following

```
fun deleteItem(id: Int) {
    items.remove(id)
    notifyItemRemoved(id)
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, I have changed it but didn't put here. The case is every element has got the same position and it;s like very huge one. It still doesn't work. I have tested it seconds ago. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: notificationAdapter.notifyItemChanged(h.absoluteAdapterPosition)}
        }).attachToRecyclerView(layout.rvNotificationItems).let {
            notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I can swipe, but it comes back to previous position and nothing happens.

Comment: Can I call this method directly from adapter ?
Like button.setOnClickListener { delete(id)}

it would be like swiped.setOnListener { make swipe function and -> delete(id)}

Comment: first of you should show your adapter code where you are removing the element. i dont think you are actuallly removing item from the data array

Comment: edited please check

Comment: I remove it from room database then getActualState to refresh

Comment: @chrisu.chrisu there is no function named `getActualState` in the whole code :(

Comment: edited 2 check this please

Comment: In that case I can provide ID from adapter and do it in viewmodel and automatically fragment notify the data is changed, but in that case I cannot directly use something like onswiping.setOnSwiped { delete when swipe and change background color}

Comment: you could use an interface for that . anyways one thing at a time. your question is about removal of object from the list. do as i have mentioned in the edit. is it working ? you are not removing the item from the items. first try doing it my way.

Comment: Removing onbutton/icon click works. ;( I need delete on swipe it doesnt because of the fact of positions ;(

Comment: I have two goals in my mind.
get the right position and use function in adapter or use function in adapter directly like button.setOnClickListner { delete}.